# Unathorized operation terraform(aws) in gitlab runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab-ci

I'm using `aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity` to run terraform from gitlab. I'm getting an error I can't find the missing IAM action for:

```
╷
│ Error: Error fetching Availability Zones: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
│   status code: 403, request id: 43a2032d-1bdd-4957-add9-070d3c270343
│ 
│   with module.vpc.data.aws_availability_zones.available,
│   on modules/terraform-aws-vpc/private.tf line 1, in data "aws_availability_zones" "available":
│    1: data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
```

data source:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}
```

I've tried multiple variations of ec2 actions, even: "ec2:*" but the issue remains.

Solutions found online usually recommend admin privileges, but I'm hoping for a better solution

Iam policy:

```
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateVpc",
      "ec2:CreateSubnet",
      "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
      "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
      "ec2:CreateRoute",
      "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
      "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
      "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
      "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
      "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ec2:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:*",
      "arn:aws:ec2::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:ipam-pool/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:ipv6pool-ec2/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:subnet/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:vpc/*"
    ]
  }
```

replacing resources with: "*" so this is causing the issue

Comment: 1. Have you tried giving the `ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones` permission?
2. Could you please paste the definition of the `aws_availability_zones` data source?
3. Could you have a prohibitive IAM policy conflicting with the given permissions?

Comment: 1. Yes I've tried this
2. Updated the issue now
3. not that I'm aware of, and not entirely sure what that means